# Cannot locate resource for a converter

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to toggle the visibility of a window.  I have bound a boolean object to my ViewModel and have a converter in place to handle the visibility toggle.  The project will run, but immediately bombs out with an exception of "Cannot find resource named 'VisibilityConverter'."

The other converters in my Windows.Resources xml are found and utilized just fine.  Why can it not find this one?  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
Window x:Class="MyProject.Views.ControlPanel"
Height="650" Width="805" MinWidth="805"
Visibility="{Binding ControlPanelWindowBo.IsWindowVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <converters:BoolToIconConverter x:Key="BoolToIconConverter" />
        <converters:BoolHomeTeamPossessionConverter x:Key="BoolHomeTeamPossessionConverter" />
        <converters:BoolVisitorTeamPossessionConverter x:Key="BoolVisitorTeamPossessionConverter" />
        <converters:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Maybe it's because it's a level to deep. Have you tried defining it (VisibilityConverter) in the app.xaml?

Comment: The VisibilityConverter is a class.  How would I define a class in the app.xmal?

Comment: Figured it out.  I just needed to declare the converters there.  Stefan - Thank you!!!!  If you form your response in the form of an answer I'll be happy to mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Your welcome, I added it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the level on which `VisibilityConverter` is defined (window level), is to deep.

You should define it in your `app.xaml` and define it as application resource:

```
<Application x:Class="stuff.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
             <converters:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />
             ...and others.
         </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```